# в чем проблема с отсутствием мьютексов в коде?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

здравствуйте, начинаю очередной раз разбираться с многопоточностью... нашел простой пример для наглядности рассинхронизации доступа, но не понимаю некоторых вещей:

```
struct Counter {
    int value;

    Counter() : value(0){}

    void increment(){
        ++value;
    }
};

int main() {
    Counter counter;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        threads.push_back(std::thread([&counter](){
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
                counter.increment();
            }
        }));
    }

    for(auto& thread : threads){
        thread.join();
    }

    std::cout << counter.value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

совершенно не могу понять почему вылетают разные значения... у нас ведь join() т.е. мы ждем когда каждый из пяти потоков выполнится один за другим(т.е. инкрементирует по 100 раз каждый), я понимаю если б detach() стоял, то была бы жесть... а так каждый поток из пяти один за другим ведь следом идут... почему значения отличные от 500 получаются. либо я чего-то не учитываю... разве не верно, что в первом потоке будет 100, и в последующих будут на 100 больше?

Comment: Вы не учитываете то, что доступ к значению без синхронизации из разных потоков — UB. Поток в отсутствие синхронизации имеет право как угодно кешировать код, преобразовывать, анроллить циклы и всё такое. Если вы считаете, что запись `++value` реально увеличивает переменную в некоторой области памяти, у меня для вас плохие новости.

Comment: то есть я правильно понимаю, что проблемы не будет когда будет лишь один поток добавлен?
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&counter](){
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
            counter.increment();
        }
    }));
    threads.at(0).join();

Comment: Гарантировано проблем только с одним потоком. Побочный поток = возможные (но не обязательные) проблемы.

Comment: что-то я вас не понял... у нас есть второй поток который инкрементирует без мьютексов и т.д. какое-то значение... это уже UB будет?

Comment: Именно так, больше одного потока = плохо. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28591924/276994

Comment: так один поток же меняет то значение всего лишь... который не основной

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44923/discussion-between-xperious-and-vladd).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас не синхронизирован доступ к `counter`, поэтому, в силу data races, как Вам уже правильно указал VladD, у Вас в коде UB. Чтобы исправить код, Вам нужно синхронизировать доступ к `counter` внутри, или снаружи. Можно сделать так:

```
struct Counter {
    std::atomic_int value;
    ...
};
```

Или так:

```
std::mutex guard;

std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&counter, &guard]() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{guard};
            counter.increment();
        }
    }));
}
```

Или ещё массой других вариантов — главное, чтобы пропали *гонки*(data races)

Answer (score 4):

Ваша главная ошибка вот:

> у нас ведь join() т.е. мы ждем когда каждый из пяти потоков выполнится один за другим

Отнюдь. Выполняться они могут как угодно. Вы ожидаете не выполнения, а *завершения*. Грубо говоря, возможна ситуация, когда первый поток выполнится последним, так что остальные `join`'ы будут к уже отработавшим потокам. Этот цикл - просто гарантия того, что отработают все потоки, а уж в каком порядке они будут работать и как - на это ваши `join`'ы никак не влияют.